# Variable that keeps its value forever?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a UI for my custom unity script I plan on selling, the script when added automatically adds another separate script called `AdditionalPlayerData`. Whilst setting up this script I want it to show some text like "This script adds some additional functionality" or whatever and then I want a button underneath that says like "I understand". I know how to add the text and button and everything but how can I make it so that once I click I understand a Boolean changes and then the pop up never appears again. I know about static variables but they all reset when the app is reloaded or restarted, and it would be kind of annoying if it asks you every time you load it up. Maybe some sort of caching json file would be necessary? But i dont really know if theres a simpler way.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorPrefs.html

Comment: that looks like it would work but can you give an example? Just a link to what i could use doesnt really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use unity's builtin PlayerPrefs class, unless you want to do some heavy-compute read/write to file. PlayerPrefs saves data to end-user's file system (some associated with app folder).
Here's main docs page:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

Here's HasKey method docs with example:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.HasKey.html

Here's my example

```
private void TryShowTipToUser(string tipId)
{
    // Check if player already seen this tip
    if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey(tipId))
    {
        return;
    }
    // or execute your code and then set some value to key
    ShowTipWithCallback(()=>SetKeyExist(tipId))
}

private void ShowTipWithCallback(Action callback)
{
    Debug.Log("Look at this, this is a tip!") // paste your code here
    callback?.Invoke();
}

private void SetKeyExist(string key)
{
    // Simpy set 1 or any other number, then unity will return "true" when HasKey called
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt(key, 1);
}
```

Comment: I would use EditorPrefs for this since it is related to something you do it the editor not any specific game or project.